# Problems with brightness and video card on an HP Compaq 6735b

Tags: video, brightness

I am kind of new to the linux world. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 a couple of weeks ago to use vim but I've been having some issues. I have a HP Compaq 6735b, 2.2 GHz AMD Turion(tm)X2 Dual Core Mobile RM-70 × 2, 2.7 GB ram DDR2, ATI Radeon HD 3200 serie.

Basically the problem i'm having is first of all installing the correct driver of my video card because it still says unknown. Second of all I cannot adjust my system's brightness. I have shorcuts on windows for FN + F9 and FN + F10 and they "occasionally" work on ubuntu but most of the time they do not work and there isn't a brightness bar in the system settings. Thanks in advance!